# History of 15 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Menachem Begin met with Anwar Sadat at Ismilia, Egypt. in 1977

2)Yartzeits

-Mesharshia bar Pakud, Amora

-Rav Huna, Amora

-Mari bar Mar Zutra, Amora

-R' Chaim Mordechai ben R' Itamar Rosenbaum of Nadvorna (1978)

-R' Noson Nota Natkin ben R' Asher (1887) was a grandson of the Shaagas Aryeh and son-in-law of R' Yosef Zundel of Salant he is buried in NY at Union Field Cemetery,because he died while collecting money for the Yishuv Hayoshon in Eretz Yisroel.

-R' Refoel of Barshad (1827) talmid of R' Pinchas Koritzer.

Answer (score 2):

1488: the first edition of the SeMaG (Sefer Mitzvos Gadol), a comprehensive list of Mitzvos was printed in Italy.

1963: Israel opened its first desalinization plant in Eilat.